# Error with qemu emulator

Tags: boot, qemu

I was writing a boot sector program(in assembly) and created the binary using nasm.

The command `od -t x1 -A n boot sect.bin` confirmed the bytes the assembler had created.

However, when I loaded qemu emulator using the command

```
qemu-x86_64 boot_sect.bin
```

I get the following error :

```
error while loading boot_sect.bin: exec format error
```